# seeds.rb in Django 1.8 - bootstrap the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Rails we have the seeds.rb file which is used to bootstrap the database. What's the idiomatic way to do that in Django 1.8, preferably using Python code? I'll need to read the some data files I have and insert the data into the db? From the documentation it's unclear.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on how to provide initial data to your database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/)? If so, what are you specifically struggling with?

Comment: @LaundroMat **preferably using Python code** That data is meant to be created statically, whereas I want to read the data from the data files I have and then insert it into the db - dynamically.

Comment: Is your data available in one of the formats Django accepts as fixtures (JSON, XML or YAML)?

Comment: It sounds like you'd want to [create your own management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/). That way, you can read in data from an external source whenever you need to (manually, via the cli or automatically, via eg a cron job).

Answer (score 1):

There is also this package [django-seed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-seed) which may be of use.